# Qt: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QProcess::ProcessError' - QProcess::ProcessError(FailedToStart)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to pass a serialized image to a process I started in my Qt program. 
However when doing so I get this error message:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QProcess::ProcessError'
(Make sure 'QProcess::ProcessError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

The image I am trying to pass is a cv::Mat which I converted to a QImage which I afterwards converted to a QString.

Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly when streaming my parameters to the variable params? My current guess is that the issue lies in the serialized form of the image ie it contains many double quotes which is why when inserting the value of matQStr in the line below (to stream it to params), there is a misinterpretation

Everything else works perfectly fine, it is just now when trying to pass an image that something goes wrong.

In case you may need this information, the process I am starting is a python function using openCV taking 1 parameter, ie the image I am trying to pass. Serializing the image to pass it to the function, apparently is the easiest solution.

The code:

```
double myClass::runPythonScrypt()
{
    cv::Mat imageParameter = cv::imread("/home/John/Desktop/image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    QImage img((uchar*)imageParameter.data, imageParameter.cols, imageParameter.rows, imageParameter.step1(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
    std::string matStdString(imageParameter.begin<unsigned char>(), imageParameter.end<unsigned char>());
    QString matQStr = QString::fromStdString(matStdString);

    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, qApp, &QApplication::aboutQt );
    int a=55;
//I added "this is the end in the string because in the beginning I thought maybe some overflow occured and therefor not the entire image was passed to the process, yet you can see that this sentence gets printed"
    params<< "-c" << "import cv2; import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); from myTest import myClass; myClassObj = myClass(); print myClassObj.myTestFunction( "+ matQStr +" ) this isthe end;";



        qDebug()<<params;
        p.start("python2", params);
        if(! p.waitForFinished(-1))
        {qDebug()<<"it failedddd";}

        qDebug()<<"error that occured: "<<p.error();

        QString errors = p.readAllStandardError();
        qDebug()<<"occured errors:"<<errors;

        QString p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();


...

}
```

The generated output:

```
started recognition thread
("-c", "import cv2; import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); from myTest import myClass; myClassObj = myClass(); print myClassObj.myTestFunction(

...etc...

����������������������Ѧ����<\u0013\u001B\u0014�������������������������������������������������������������������
����������������������������������������������������������������������u0011\u0017\u0005\b=
*\u0007\u0005\u0016=/\"6=;<@@;;>AA@:311373//+1HcVFPs\u007FeH?z\u007FBY�f\\�oJV��������������������t?
>K\\`RJMTY`a[RSWQMJECBDDIEEEJKN
KJGJHF>@AGFHDC=<89:AA<0/4*%%+/../+##.657>9;=@BBBA@A@><:9<?@@?>?BB;;:88:;<>;;;>>=<;<@@>=<<<;:::;;<998:7337:;<;:
88955555677;;956:954578887879::8533146764441/./0110/--0563/1220./2665420/011222147;FEA>?>;8>=<BGG;04,,-%$&$ \")0
1./3332/,))++)),.)

etc...

10210.,,,-.-/12/*'',-023432-%#')')/04;94:<3.).51/1.((*.10,'1/23547702.0%#0+114; ) this isthe end;")

started recognition thread
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QProcess::ProcessError'
(Make sure 'QProcess::ProcessError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
it failedddd
error that occured:  QProcess::ProcessError(FailedToStart)
occured errors: ""
name:  ""
certitude:  0
return value:  0
2
```

**EDIT:**

The used python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import cv2
import os
import numpy as np


class myClass:

    def __init__(self): pass

    def myTestfunction2(self):     
        image= cv2.imread("/home/John/Desktop/image1.jpg")
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

    def myTestFunction(self, a):
        print('my test function showing passed image as parameter')
        cv2.imshow('a', a)        
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        return ('John', a)
```

Note that this line, to stream the parameters in stead of the one currently in my software works perfectly fine:

```
params<< "-c" << "import cv2; import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); from myTest import myClass; myClassObj = myClass(); print myClassObj.myTestFunction(cv2.imread('/home/John/Desktop/image1.jpg'));";
```

But it doesn t do exactly what I need, I need to pass a cpp variable rather than using cv2.imread()

Comment: You can show the .py

Comment: @eyllanesc added the python script

Comment: From what I see in your code, you are reading an image, you convert it to string and you want to pass it as part of an argument to qprocess, I think that somewhere in that string the character ")" appears, ie `...myTestFunction(partial_string) Another_partial)...` that is causing the application not to start.

Comment: @eyllanesc well, QProcess perfectly showed him that system didn't even start python, so it doesn't matter is actual python code correct or not, he use giantic argument which is forbidden in linux, that's why system didn't even start app. More info in my answer below

Comment: Good point, I had not taken it into account, that is the most probable.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see in your code registering `metaType` line, so please try:

```
QProcess p;
QStringList params;
qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError"); // new line
connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, qApp, &QApplication::aboutQt );
```

This should solve

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QProcess::ProcessError'
(Make sure 'QProcess::ProcessError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

problem, so your connection will work and you will see about `Qt` window, but if for some reasons `QProcess` wasn't able to start, then it will still have original source of problem, so ^ is just fix for connection.

Anyways `QProcess` showed you source of problem here:

```
 error that occured:  QProcess::ProcessError(FailedToStart)
```

and quite oftenly it means that you try to use some wrong path. Please recheck path or try to use `absolutePath`, maybe it will solve original problem.

**EDIT:**

Ok, after your comment it's clear, well `linux` can't accept unlimited amount of data in arguments, you try to encode here very big amount of info, check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852071/argument-list-too-long-error) f.e. So actually your first approach has normal length and it works, now you pass giantic piece of info and you don't even run python, yes, it's correct path, but system just reject it and show you `QProcess::ProcessError(FailedToStart)`, of course it could be more convenient with info like `... has too big argument` or smth like that, but we don't have it.

**Summary:**

So your approach is just impossible to implement (also different systems have different limits, so it seems that it's even dangerous (not-portable)), so you need to rewrite your app. I can only suggest to try to save `tmp` file from `Qt` and pass `tmp` path to `python` script like it was suggested in the link above.

But the best approach probably is just compile `OpenCV` for `C++/Qt` and work with raw `OpenCV` code directly here without `tmp` files or etc, this will increase `performance` a lot. Talk about this with your `team`, if it is some task or do `as you wish` if it's your `personal` project.

Comment: OK, added the line you added, indeed it solved the registration problem. the path is 100% correct. As stated, this line works perfectly fine as long as I don't pass an image. The error probably lies in the way the image is serialized and streamed to the variable params (which is the main cause of my issue I suppose). What do you suggest for the FailedToStart error?

Comment: Note that this line, to stream the parameters in stead of the one currently in my software works perfectly fine:

    params<< "-c" << "import cv2; import imp; foo = imp.load_source('myTest', '/home/John/fw/demos/myTest.py'); from myTest import myClass; myClassObj = myClass(); print myClassObj.myTestFunction(cv2.imread('/home/John/Desktop/image1.jpg'));";


But it doesn t do exactly what I need, I need to pass a cpp variable rather than using cv2.imread()

Comment: @trilolil please check edit, I can't help more unfortunately, unless my thoughts about big argument list are wrong